# How to create a simple AVPlayer streaming App?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, avplayer

How to create a simple iPhone app that uses AVPlayer to stream internet radio?
I followed this documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html) from IOS Developer Guide, however I'm not getting a result. Attached are my .h and .m files.

```
#import "Bbcradio.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation Bbcradio

- (IBAction)play:sender {
    [player play];
}

self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:@"http://bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r1.asx"];
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&PlayerStatusContext];

@end
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AVPlayerLayer;

@interface Bbcradio : UIView {

}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;

-(IBAction)play;

@end
```

Comment: Your question is far too vague and at the moment is unanswerable. You need to ask a specific question. Anything that asks "Guide me" is overly broad for this website.

Comment: Thanks Jackslash - to be more speficic, is the above code correct if I want to create a streaming app using AvPlayer?Am I missing something here?
Thanks.

Comment: Im sorry but you have a long way to go. The player setup code is outside of any method and will never be run. `AVPlayer` doesn't even support ASX streams. Also to top it off all the above code is set in a `UIView` which violates Model View Controller design pattern. The solution you seek is too complex for an answer here.

Comment: Ok-My understanding is not correct then.
what I thought was to declare it in the .h file, then add the play action and the AvPlayer item with the link then that's good.
would you know any particular book or link that explains Audio/Video streaming for iPhone app design, please?
Appreciate your help here. cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry to have to be the one to say it but no, its not. I recommend going right back to basics and doing some more tutorials or courses from the beginning. There is a great course on iTunes U called CS193P, check out https://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to play an audio stream in a format not supported by iOS. That URL is an [ASX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Stream_Redirector) which eventually redirects to Windows Media streams. AVPlayer isn't going to play that because iOS doesn't have built in support for Windows Media (and probably can't deal with the ASX either). Check out [Apple's list of supported audio formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX.html) for details on what AVPlayer can handle.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the info. Looks like I really need to learn more about AvPlayer in order to do audio streaming, unless there is another way of doing this.
Cheers.

Comment: I think you're using it correctly, you just need to stick to compatible audio formats.